# sudo access per folder? is that possible?

Tags: users, sudo

is it possible to give sudo privileges to a user for a specific folder?
e.g i want the user 'dads' to have sudo access for creating/deleting files in a folder 'virgo' in /opt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, i'm pretty sure you can't, but you can let other users read/write in that folder by changing it's permissions.

Another approach is to create a group, set that group as the owner of the folder, and then add all the users you want to that group.

Answer (score 1):

For complex file/folder permissions scenarios, consider the use of ACLs. Otherwise I second the answer of sebikul.